# Error with loading data using StellarGraph

Tags: python, http-status-code-403, loaddata

I run this code on Colab more times with no problem,

```
import stellargraph as sg
from IPython.display import display, HTML
dataset = sg.datasets.Cora()
display(HTML(dataset.description))
G, node_subjects = dataset.load()
```

but suddenly this error appear

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: i type {User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.46} but obtain invalid syntax error

Comment: i tried this code `import requests`
`dataset = sg.datasets.Cora()`
`url='http://<stellargraph.datasets.datasets.Cora>'`
`headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.73'}`
`display(HTML(dataset.description))`
`G, node_subjects = requests.get(url, headers=headers)`

Comment: this error appears  HTTPConnectionPool(host='%3cstellargraph.datasets.datasets.cora%3e', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f44a60909d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this appear because the url is no longer valid,

checking source code, https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/9370caed1137c2527523a39212072df1760ca00f/stellargraph/datasets/datasets.py#L104

paste the url into browser also give you 403

ultimate reason is seems this university delete all the data or restricted everyone to view it, check
https://linqs-data.soe.ucsc.edu/

cora dataset may be found [https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mccallum/data/](https://people.cs.umass.edu/%7Emccallum/data/) or [https://web.archive.org/web/20150918182409/http://www.cs.umd.edu/~sen/lbc-proj/data/cora.tgz](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918182409/http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esen/lbc-proj/data/cora.tgz)

or you could choose to use other datasets for link prediction , wn18 ,etc

Comment: The code was already run without any editing.

Comment: yup, their database is up again.